# how can I change the home directory of a user

Tags: user-accounts, ubuntu-12.04

I just changed the username of an existing user by doing:

```
usermod -l new_username old_username
```

and now I wanted to change the home directory using the following:

```
 chown -R root.new_username .bash* .profile /home/new_username
```

however it always gives me:

```
 chown: invalid user: `root.newuser'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Something is wrong what you are doing and I don't get it why you want to change root user files owner.

Do you trying to rename the root user folder and  owner of the files.

whay is the connection between root, old_user and new_user?

Comment: I thing your answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username

Answer (score 1):

Replace `root.new_user` with `root:new_user`

Comment: nope, didn't work as well, chown: invalid group: `root:new_user'

Comment: Some OSes (like Ubuntu) accepts both `'.'` (dot) and `':'` (colon).

Comment: yea, but it didn't work

Comment: @adit | You might want to double check your user has actually changed. If it shows your new_user maybe a system restart might be useful.